# Set Javascript output vertical alignment to middle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a Javascript clock showing in a thin frame:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/kyoZ5c8.png]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <TITLE>Untitled</TITLE>
  <SCRIPT>
      function checkTime(i) {
        if (i < 10) {
            i = "0" + i;
        }
        return i;
      }
      function startTime() {
        var today = new Date();
        var h = today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();
        // add a zero in front of numbers<10
        m = checkTime(m);
        s = checkTime(s);
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
        t = setTimeout(function () {
            startTime()
        }, 500);
      }
  </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="startTime()">
  <DIV id="time" style="width: 95px; height: 32px; border: solid; border-width: thin; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"><p>time</p></DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Unfortunately, I cannot get the vertical alignment inside the frame to MIDDLE, although I have set `vertical-align: middle`.

So how can I center it vertically?

Comment: `line-height: 32px;` should do the trick

Comment: Thank you! Put in an answer, so I can check it.

Comment: And then remove onload from the body tag and have `window.onload=function() { setInterval(startTime,500);}` that way you can remove the `t = setTimeout(function () {
            startTime()
        }, 500);` too - like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/f8svc8k4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `vertical-align` property applies to inline level and table-cell elements; and `div`'s `display` property is `block` by default, so `vertical-align` property is ignored.

Use `line-height: 32px`(same as the `height`) instead.

```js
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}

function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  // add a zero in front of numbers<10
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    startTime()
  }, 500);
}
```

```html
<body onload="startTime()">
  <div id="time" style="width: 95px; height: 32px; border: solid; border-width: thin; text-align: center; line-height: 32px;">
    <p>time</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `line-height` property:

```
line-height: 32px;
```

```js
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  // add a zero in front of numbers<10
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  t = setTimeout(function () {
    startTime()
  }, 500);
}
startTime();
```

```html
<DIV id="time" style="width: 95px; height: 32px; border: solid; border-width: thin; text-align: center; line-height: 32px;"><p>time</p></DIV>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest solution: Use `line-height: 32px;`. That will make the line itself as high as the box, and the text will be more or less centered depending on the font.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py has rendered this answer completely useless. :D